# Concatenate cells if they are in a certain range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula to concatenate cell values (say A1:E1) to G1 if they are in a certain range, like cells values are smaller than < 7, or cell values are between 8 and 15, etc.

I tried to create a formula like this : =concatenate(if(A1:E1<7,"")) which is not correct. I couldn't find similar example on the internet either.

Example:

```
A1:1 | B1:2 | C1:3 | D1:5 | E1:50  

Concatenate if A1:E1 is smaller than 7 => Result :  G1: (1,2,3,5)
Concatenate if A1:E1 is between 1 and 7 => Result : G1: (2,3,5)
Concatenate if A1:E1 is bigger than 10 => Result :  G1: (50)
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A1:E1<=7,A1:E1,""))
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((A1:E1<=7)*(A1:E1>1),A1:E1,""))
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((A1:E1>=10),A1:E1,""))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

TEXTJOIN was introduced in Office 365 Excel.  If you do not have that then it will require vba.  Put the following in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: I just tried =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A1:E1<=7,A1:E1,"")) but I get #NAME? error.

Comment: @Max see the edits, you may need to refresh your screen.

Comment: Yes, I did what you said, and your formula worked. But when I tried this formula =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(2<A1:E1<=7,A1:E1,"")), it gave #VALUE! error. Can you also tell me how I should write the formula for a range between numbers, please?

Comment: @Max see the Answer above I gave all three formulas.

Comment: can I ask a question? I entered all formulas, everything was a fine, I got the results, a little while later, everything turns to #Name? error. I didn't change anything on macro or data. Do you have any suggestion for this? thanks.